# “but, except, besides”?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, bare-infinitive, gerund-vs-infinitive

When learning the infinitive construction, my teacher told us that if “but, except, besides” serves as a preposition and before them there exists “do” or its other forms (did, does), “but, except, besides” will be followed by an infinitive with “to” being omitted, such as “He wants to do nothing but go out.” 
I am wondering if you could give me an example about “besides” followed by an infinitive with “to” being omitted.

In addition, I found this sentence in a dictionary “Besides making money, the company aims to set high standards of quality and design.” I thought “besides” could be followed by an infinitive and gerund. Am I right? Is there any differences? In addition, can "but" or except" be followed by a gerund ?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Typos and spelling mistakes happen to us all (or at least, they happen to me a lot), but it's worth particularly checking the spelling of a word you are asking about. I had no idea what *besieds* was when I saw this question in the list.

Comment: See also [ell.se]

Answer (score 2):

> I did nothing that day besides eat and sleep.

It would not be as common as the other two.

It's worth noting also, the question of whether one can use *beside* here instead of *besides*. *Besides* and *beside* were once pretty much interchangeable, but have moved apart (along with a few uses dying out entirely). Unfortunately, people don't quite agree on just what way they moved apart, and as such some would say *beside* was just as good and of those a subset would use it naturally, while some others would argue that this is wrong (or at least obsolete), and can only be *besides*. It may be well to favour *besides* in your own use, but not be critical should someone choose *beside* in the same place.

Both the bare infinitive and the gerund can be used with all three of the prepositions you mention. Your example, for instance, could also be expressed as "he cares about nothing except going out".

Comment: Additional data point: my first thought when I saw your quote was "Surely that should be *beside*".  So perhaps better to avoid the word entirely while learning; it's slightly controversial, and elderly besides.

Comment: This reminds me of linked *nothing but/more/other than* situation. “I wanted to do nothing more than eat and sleep that day.”